# Invariant subspace and the irreducibility of a representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Below is one definition for the irreducible representation:

> For a group $G$, a $G-$representation $V$ is said to be irreducible if
>   there is no nontrivial proper subspace of it that is $G-$invariant.

In the $Q2\ (c)$ of this note: https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2013/math/algebra1/Solution10.pdf, it talked about the irreducibility of the hyperplane. That is:

> Consider $G=S_{4}$, and $V=\mathbb{C}^{4}$ a permuted representation associated to the action of $S_{4}$ on the canonical coordinates.

Then, in the part $(b)$, it showed that

> $V$ is the direct sum $V=V_{1}\oplus V_{2}$ of two irreducible representations $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ that are not isomorphic.

In part $(c)$, it asks the reader to show that $W$ is $S_{4}-$invariant and then conclude from here that $W$ is irreducible.

I have no problem with the invariance. But then, the note seems directly using $(b)$ to conclude that $V=W+W^{\perp}$, and $W$ is irreducible without talking about why.

It is indeed true that $W$ is $S_{4}$-invariant, but then how do I know if it has a subspace that is also $S_{4}-$invariant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This representation of $ S_4 $ clearly has a single one-dimensional irrep in its decomposition, since any element spanning such an irrep must be fixed by any even permutation in $ S_4 $ (since the only one-dimensional irreps of $ S_4 $ are those of its abelianization $ C_2 $, i.e. the trivial and the sign representations) and then it's trivial to show this element must be $ (1, 1, 1, 1) $ up to multiplication by a scalar.

This forces there to be only one other irrep in the direct sum decomposition of dimension $ 3 $, since dimension $ > 3 $ doesn't fit into the four dimensional space $ \mathbb C^4 $ and dimension $ 2 $ would require the decomposition to be like $ 1 \oplus 1 \oplus 2 $, implying two irreps of dimension $ 1 $, which we know to be impossible by the above argument. This means the representation looks like $ 1 \oplus 3 $, and the two irreducible components are clearly not isomorphic since they have different dimensions.

Comment: but why the hyperplane $W$ is irreducible? It is only invariant, right?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I gave the argument for why it is irreducible. If $ W $ were not irreducible, then it must have an irreducible subrepresentation of dimension $ 1 $, and that's impossible because we know there is only one such irreducible component of the original representation and it's the orthogonal complement of $ W $.

Comment: so.. by your argument here.. why do we need the $S_{4}-$invariance property? It seems that you did not use it at all.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I'm not sure what you're trying to say. What invariance property are you talking about?

Comment: A linear subspace $W\subset V$ is called $G-$invariant it $\rho(g)w\in W$ for all $g\in G$ and all $w\in W$. Then the restriction of $\rho$ to a $G-$invariant subspace $W\subset V$ is the subrepresentation. A representation $\rho:G\longrightarrow GL(V)$ is said to be irreducible if it has only trivial $G-$invariant subrepresentation.

Comment: and the note proves the in our case $W$ is $S_{4}-$invariant and it concludes from here that $W$ is irreducible... I don't know why.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Well, proving that a subspace is invariant doesn't imply it's irreducible, so either you're not quoting the note properly or the note is just wrong.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification!